# What event am I supposed to capture to catch checkbox changes in a XUL tree?

Tags: checkbox, tree, xul

I have this bit of XUL

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://zotero-report-customizer/skin/options.css"?>
<!DOCTYPE window SYSTEM "chrome://zotero-report-customizer/locale/zotero-report-customizer.dtd">
<prefwindow id="zotero-report-customizer-perf" title="&zotero-report-customizer.name;" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" onload="initializePrefs();">
  <stringbundleset id="stringbundleset">
    <stringbundle id="zotero-report-customizer-options" src="chrome://zotero-report-customizer/locale/options.properties" />
    <stringbundle id="zotero-options" src="chrome://zotero/locale/zotero.properties" />
  </stringbundleset>
  <prefpane label="&zotero-report-customizer.remove;" id="zotero-report-customizer-perfpane">
    <preferences id="preferences"/>
    <groupbox>
      <caption label="&zotero-report-customizer.remove;" />
      <tree flex="1" id="treeCollection" seltype="single" hidecolumnpicker="true" height="400" editable="true" onselect="togglePref(this);">
        <treecols>
          <treecol id="show" primary="true" type="checkbox" label="Show" editable="true" width="40"/>
          <treecol id="field" label="Field" editable="false" flex="1"/>
        </treecols>
        <treechildren id="itemTypes"/>
      </tree>
    </groupbox>
  </prefpane>
  <script src="chrome://zotero/content/include.js" />
  <script src="chrome://zotero-report-customizer/content/include.js" />
  <script src="options.js" />
</prefwindow>
```

I add tree rows with checkboxes dynamially; they show up just fine. But what "on...." event am I suppused to catch to notice checkboxes being toggled? Onselect doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

I originally mis-understood your question....

You can't add event handlers to the rows/cols/cells of the tree, only to the `<tree>` itself. E.g: you could detect a 'click' event on the tree -- you'd then need to figure out *what* was clicked, and finally, what you should do about it.

MDN [snippet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tree?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Code_snippets/Tree#Getting_the_cell_from_a_mouse_click) for getting `<treecell>` from mouse click event:

XUL:

```
<tree id="my-tree" onclick="onTreeClicked(event)">
```

JavaScript:

```
function onTreeClicked(event){
  var tree = document.getElementById("my-tree");
  var tbo = tree.treeBoxObject;

  // get the row, col and child element at the point
  var row = { }, col = { }, child = { };
  tbo.getCellAt(event.clientX, event.clientY, row, col, child);

  var cellText = tree.view.getCellText(row.value, col.value);
  alert(cellText);
}
```

At this point, instead of alerting the `cellText` you should check if the `treeCell` (in `checkbox` mode) is checked (or not) and act accordingly.

Paraphrasing from the `<tree>` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/tree) on MDN:

```
var cellChecked = tree.view.getCellValue(row.value, col.value) == 'true';
```

**edit:**  Make sure the cols/cells are marked as `editable` or this might not work!